# Precompile not working with Razor views in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, precompile

I'm trying to precompile razor views but during the build VS2010 throws errors such as "@ViewBag does not exist in the current context." The project builds and runs fine when views are not precompiled.

In order to turn on view compilation I set the following node in the project file:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

The section below exists in the Views Web.config file.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Xml"/>
        <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Any ideas why the project won't build?

Comment: `ViewBag` instead of `Viewbag` ?

Comment: No. Sorry, that is a typo in my question. I also get the error with any of the Razor objects/properties. (I've edited the question to correct the typo.)

Comment: It's been awhile, but off the top of my head did you have a look at <EnableUpdatable>false</EnableUpdatable> ?

Check against - https://chrismckee.co.uk/asp-net-mvc-compiled-views/

Comment: That node didn't exist. Added it, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geeze, do I ever feel like an idiot. Turns out there were some cshtml files in a _temp folder that resided inside of the project folder. Even though the folder was excluded from the solution the compiler was picking up the files contained therein. Moving that _temp file out of the project folder fixed the issue.

Comment: thanks - yeah I deleted /obj/ and it got rid of the junk that wasn't building.